# Arm Instructions

Tags: android, assembly, arm, reverse-engineering

i wanted to ask what is happening in arm instruction here. I have knowledge of ASM but i am having hard time understanding ARM. I try to look up the info on the internet that gives the basics but the thing i am looking at is a little different. So here is a code i am trying to understand.. Can you please explain what these instructions are doing. I will mark the ones i dont understand. Its a code from IDA. Can someone please explain the entire function. i will really be grateful. Thanks

```
LDR             R3, =(unk_E9BFB0 - 0x6B1B4C)  //This once,i dont get it, is it subtracting?
LDR             R8, [R5]
MOV             R1, R6
ADD             R3, PC, R3
LDR             LR, [R4,#0xC]  //This instruction
LDR             R12, =(aDraw_debug - 0x6B1B68) //This once
MOV             R2, R7
STR             R8, [R3,#0x30]
MOV             R0, R3
STR             R4, [R3]
ADD             R12, PC, R12 ; "draw_debug"  //This once 
STR             R3, [R5]
STR             R12, [R3,#0x2C]
ADD             R12, LR, #1
STR             R12, [R4,#0xC]
BL              __aeabi_atexit
```

Comment: Did you try ARM's [website](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0041c/Babbfdih.html)?

Comment: "Can someone please explain the entire function?" In short, no. a) It's apparently not an "entire function" because there's no return at the end, and b) it's a series of instructions that reads some memory addresses, computes some offsets, and writes some memory addresses - I highly doubt anyone can explain _why_ without far more context than it would be possible to reproduce here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LDR` is the instruction on ARM to load a register with a value from memory. The following, however, are the pseudoinstruction form of `LDR`:

```
LDR             R3, =(unk_E9BFB0 - 0x6B1B4C)  //This once,i dont get it, is it subtracting?
LDR             R12, =(aDraw_debug - 0x6B1B68) //This once
```

I believe it is constructing an offset from a code location to pull data out of the `.text` section. `aDraw_debug - 0x6B1B68`, for example, is likely taking the address of label `aDraw_debug`, and subtracting the location of some instruction, `0x6B1B68`.

The end result is that this essentially will load the offset of `aDraw_debug` (from an arbitrary point) into `R12`. Likewise, the other instruction will load `unk_E9BFB0` into `R3`. That one is probably compiler-generated data because of the mangled name.

The other `LDR` instruction:

```
LDR             LR, [R4,#0xC]  //This instruction
```

are a straightforward affair. `LDR` is still being used to load a register from memory, but the addressing is different. In this case, `LR`, the link register, is being loaded with the data at address `R4 + 0xC` in memory.

The `ADD` is straightforward as well, and I'm not sure if your were confused as to what it was doing but:

```
ADD             R12, PC, R12 ; "draw_debug"  //This once
```

this simply adds `PC + R12` and stores it in `R12` without updating the processor flags. This takes the offset determined earlier and applies it to the current `PC`.

Overall, it looks like this is code to store values into some sort of `struct` or `class`. The compiler chose to do PC-relative addressing, but the offset is likely outside of the usable range for the instruction. PC-relative `LDR/STR` instructions can only address +/- 4096 from `PC`.

Answer (score 0):

The ldr reg,=something is a shortcut.  The arm is a mostly fixed length instruction set or lets say there are not enough bits to allow for any possible immediate value.  Also this shortcut allows you to use labels, load the address of some label into this register.  What the assembler does with this is when it generates the machine code it allocates a word location somewhere not too far away that is not in the execution path (after an unconditional branch or bx for example).  Then for the ldr reg,= instruction it encodes a pc relative instruction ldr reg,[pc,+offset] to load that value into the register.  This allows for any 32 bit value to be loaded, no restrictions.  It also allows for labels to be used where the data value (address) is filled in later by the linker.  Your example takes that one further and does math on a label, so the assembler or linker will have to resolve the label, do the math, then put that value in the word location.

Answer (score 0):

- [ARM.COM Arm instruction Set](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/instruction-set-architectures/index.php)
- [Info Center of ARM.com - Quick Reference Cards for ARM instruction set](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.qrc0001l/QRC0001_UAL.pdf)
- [Doc for ARM instruction set](http://simplemachines.it/doc/arm_inst.pdf)
- [Indexed for each instruction web page](http://www.heyrick.co.uk/assembler/qfinder.html)
- [Arm-instructionset](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~ranido/mc404/arm/arm-instructionset.pdf)
- [Embedded Systems Architecture: The ARM Instruction Set Architecture by Mark McDermott With   help from ourgood friends at ARM](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~valvano/EE345M/Arm_EE382N_4.pdf)